# TSC build errors during github-action but compiles fine locally

Tags: typescript, github-actions

Using `act` to locally test github-actions via Docker, I am getting a variety of TS errors (TS2345, TS18046, TS2339, etc...) during my github-action workflow.  These errors are **not** observed during local development and running `tsc -p tsconfig.build.json` on my local machine results in a successful compilation.

The github-action runs on `ubuntu-latest` and I have confirmed that the runner is configured to use the same versions of node, npm, yarn and tsc as my local.

- Node - `v18.13.0`
- npm - `v8.19.3`
- yarn - `1.22.19`
- tsc - `v4.9.4`

Furthermore, I have confirmed that the config TSC uses during the github-action is identical to my local config (output from `tsc --showConfig`, compared diff from local and github-action).  Using the same docker container from the github-action, I can access the terminal and run the same commands without seeing the errors.

Given that the node, npm, yarn and tsc versions are the same across my local and github-action, what could possible cause this different behavior?

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "incremental": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "paths": {
    "@module": ["src/module"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it was caused by not having all the packages listed in package.json.

I'm still not sure why it built successfully locally (perhaps I had leftover files in node_modules?) but I traced the error messages to the specific lines and found that it was due to a particular import that was missing.  Added it to package.json and the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question was asked quite some time ago, I just posted a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76368227/tsc-doesnt-output-errors-from-strict-in-my-terminal-but-the-github-action-fa/76368368#76368368), perhaps this'll help you out as well. Basically, not installing the required packages in your workflow can cause other TS errors. Simply adding `uses: npm install` before `run: tsc -p tsconfig.json` did the job for me.

Comment: I get missing version for action when adding `uses: npm install`

Comment: Getting error that uses cannot be used like this.