# NPM compilation error with express-rate-limit running on GitHub action while locally compiles fine

Tags: node.js, npm

trying to rollout a new version of my backend service through GitHub action but it produces the following error when running 'npm run check'.

```
> gts-auth@1.2.6 check
> tsc --noEmit

Error: src/routes/signup.ts(18,50): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

The corresponding JS code in signup.ts in that auth service looks as follows:

```
import express, { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit'
import { body } from 'express-validator'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
// ...

const allowlist = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1']

const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 5,
    message: 'Too many requests from this IP! Try later',
    skip: (request, response) => allowlist.includes(request.ip), // <-- error is triggered here
    standardHeaders: true, // Return rate limit info in the `RateLimit-*` headers
    legacyHeaders: false // Disable the `X-RateLimit-*` headers
})

const router = express.Router()
///...
```

Btw. countless rollouts happened with the very same unchanged JS code / signup.ts and it always passed the compilation step.

Also noteworthy, npm run check pulls less packages on my local machine with the same node version (v16.20.2) as compared to the GitHub action:

- locally 'npm install' outputs:
  `added 681 packages, and audited 682 packages in 7s`
- on github 'npm install' outputs:
  `added 686 packages, and audited 687 packages in 23s`

so that's 5 more packages (yes, I made sure to clean out my local npm_modules folder and freshly run 'npm i')

I have no idea why rate-limit-express works fine on my local environment and does not pass the comilation check on my GitHub rollout pipeline.

--

According to this SO thread one should simply add '-uses npm i' to the steps of the gitHub job:
[TSC build errors during github-action but compiles fine locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75269388/tsc-build-errors-during-github-action-but-compiles-fine-locally)

However, I already use the following npm install as a separate step before checking for compilation errors:

```
jobs:
    Run-Unit-Tests:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        #...
        steps:
            - name: Check out gts-auth
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Use Node.js 16, install and run tests
              uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                  node-version: 16
                  token: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
                  registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
                  always-auth: true

            - name: Install npm packages
              working-directory: auth
              run: npm i
              env:
                  NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

            - name: Check compilation errors
              #uses: npm install # <-- complains: Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate.yaml-schema: GitHub Workflow
              working-directory: auth
              run: npm run check

            - name: Run tests
              working-directory: auth
              run: npm run test
```

And adding 'npm i' directly to scripts in my package.json does not do the trick, either:

```
"scripts": {
        "check": "npm i && tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.json",
        // ...
    },
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: By adding undefined checks of the request and request.ip the compilation error is fixed on GitHub, but still I would really like to know why the Github workflow detects that error while on the local machine with the same environment does not.